# Set MIME type of Javascript audio object

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

To support HLS audio streaming on a HTML5 Audio tag, we can successfully use this MIME type:

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="AUDIO_URL" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</audio>
```

However if I create the audio element programmatically, I can't seem to specify what the MIME type should be.  Because I'm not able to provide that specific MIME type for HLS audio streaming (m3u8 extension) the audio playback fails.

How can I specify a MIME type when creating a new `Audio()` in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to build up the same structure that you have in your HTML with JavaScript.

```
const audio = new Audio();
const source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src', 'AUDIO_URL');
source.setAttribute('type', 'application/x-mpegURL');

audio.append(source);
audio.play();
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  But I guess what it shows me is Audio completely relies on Source for defining the MIME type, and there's no other method that doesn't require a child element.  Now I just need to figure out how to swap out the Source element in order to switch between multiple live audio streams.